# Can't Remove Activity Title in My Android Project With minSdkVersion=9, targetSdkVersion=21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

i am new to android. 
i am trying to hide the title bar of my activity but i failed every time.

my style.xml is

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Failed Attempt 1**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**Failed Attempt 2**

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**Failed Attempt 3**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

My Activity is

```
public class JobDetailsView extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_details_view);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these style in your resource file.

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">     
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>     
</style>
```

And add this theme to your application and activity,

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

In manifest file,hope it should work.

Note:Keep in mind you should not extend **ActionBarActivity** instead try with **Activity** in your activity class.Then it will work.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Used this in manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in `oncreate()` method.

before:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
```

Or you can use

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar
```

Comment: oh i got the issue, i was extending it from ActionBarActivity, when i changed the extended to extends Activity, it worked!